# Data streaming between two processes

Tags: java, process, data-stream

I have two java processes and I have to write data generated from one process as an input to the other java process. The data stream generated will be of the size of 5GB . How can I do that.

Do I have to use a buffer file and read and write inputstream/outputstream into that file. Is there no other method or a more efficient method?

Thanks

Comment: Is this streaming data, or static files on a storage device?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Sockets rather than an intermediate file.

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/WriteTextToSocket.html

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/ReadFromSocket.html

If you're using threads (and not processes), a PipedInputStream should work.